# Was Kramer ever gainfully employed?

Tags: seinfeld

In Seinfeld, Kramer is shown to be able to afford a flat alone in Jerry's building. While we see Jerry, George and Elaine several times at work, we never see Kramer holding down a job.

The only instances I remember is him being hired as an extra in a Woody Allen film (These pretzels are making me thirsty), and his tennis ballboy (ball-man?) gig. But I don't remember the whole series.

Canonically, did he ever have a steady job during or before the events of the series? What were the sources of his income?

Comment: This Quora post has great answers to your questions: http://www.quora.com/How-does-Kramer-pay-for-his-apartment-on-Seinfeld

Comment: As for a steady job, in season 9's [The Strike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Strike_%28Seinfeld%29) (the Festivus episode) we find out that Kramer *did* work - he was in H&H Bagels and is actually on a 12-year strike.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kramer had a ton of odd [jobs](http://www.vulture.com/2013/05/all-of-kramers-jobs-and-schemes-on-seinfeld.html). Including:

> Chief executive officer. (Founded the think tank Kramerica
>   Industries.)
>
> Culinary entrepreneur. (Conceptualized a chain of make-your-own-pizza
>   parlors and a restaurant that only serves peanut butter and jelly
>   sandwiches called “P B and Js.”)
>
> Inventor. (Conceived the idea for tie dispensers in restaurants to
>   replace patrons’ soiled ones.)
>
> Movie actor. (Got one line in a Woody Allen movie.)
>
> Sitcom actor. (Guest-starred on hit series Murphy Brown.)
>
> Expert gambler. (Gainfully anticipated winning outcomes in basketball,
>   horse races, and flight arrival times.)
>
> Perfumer. (Developed a beach-scented cologne.)
>
> Portrait model. (Posed for a painting that sold for $5,000 to a couple
>   who described him as “an innocent orphan in the postmodern world.”)
>
> Screenwriter. (Developed a movie treatment titled The Keys.)
>
> Scalper. (Flipped an opera ticket for a $400 profit.)
>
> Model. (Showcased in a Calvin Klein underwear ad campaign.)
>
> Record Salesman. (Appropriated old vinyl LPs to sell to music shops.)
>
> Tennis ball boy.
>
> Small-business investor. (Provided funding to a local nonfat
>   frozen-yogurt shop.)
>
> Soap-opera stand-in. (Worked on the set of All My Children.)
>
> Clothing distributor  (Sold “The Executive,” a beltless trenchcoat
>   invented by Jerry’s father in 1946, to Rudy's Antique Boutique.)
>
> Author. (Wrote The Coffee Table Book of Coffee Tables featured on Live
>   With Regis and Kathie Lee.)
>
> Beauty-pageant coach and chaperone. (Advised a Miss America contestant
>   on her interview, appearance, and talent.)
>
> Vintage-clothing salesman. (Sold Kenny Bania the suit off his back for
>   $300.)
>
> Department-store Santa Claus.
>
> Police lineup stand-in.
>
> Intimate apparel designer. (Co-inventor of “the Bro”/“Manssiere,” “a
>   support undergarment specifically designed for men.”)
>
> Plaintiff. (Sued coffee company for burning him with their scalding
>   café latte.)
>
> Sports memorabilia appropriator. (Sold George Steinbrenner’s birthday
>   card signed by the entire Yankee organization.)
>
> Fireman.
>
> Moviefone man impersonator. (Provides callers with movie time and
>   theater information when they mistakenly dial his number, 555-FILK.)
>
> Cinéaste. (Collaborates on the reopening of a revival movie house
>   called the Alex.)
>
> Hansom cab driver.
>
> Plaintiff. (Sued Oh Henry! candy bar heiress Sue Ellen Mischke for
>   causing his car accident when she walked down the street wearing just
>   a bra.)
>
> Bottle exporter. (Tried to recycle truckloads of bottles in Michigan,
>   where the refund rate per container is twice that of New York’s.)
>
> Customer service tester. (Capitalized on a local bank’s policy
>   promising $100 to anyone not greeted by a teller with a “hello” —
>   though he ultimately only received $20.)
>
> Author. (Wrote the book Astonishing Tales of the Sea, which chronicles
>   the Andrea Doria ship collision.)
>
> Office worker. (“T.C.B.” as in “taking care of business,” for the
>   Brandt-Leland company.)
>
> Photographer. (Snapped pictures for a variety of purposes from
>   Christmas cards to intimate shots.)
>
> Party planner. (Organized a Jewish singles dance.)
>
> Tour guide. (Provided housing and entertainment for Japanese
>   businessmen visiting Manhattan.)
>
> Plaintiff. (Sued a tobacco company for ruining his good looks.)
>
> Cock fighter.
>
> Ghost writer. (Sells J. Peterman his life stories to use in Peterman’s
>   autobiography.)
>
> Cigar manufacturer. (Hires Cubans to roll cigars; unfortunately they
>   turn out to be Dominican.)
>
> Specialty sightseeing tour creator. (Conducts his three-hour “Peterman
>   Reality Tour" using a school bus.)
>
> Lifeguard.
>
> Industrial inventor. (Creates a rubber bladder system for oil tankers
>   in an effort to “put an end to maritime oil spills.”)
>
> Condiment inventor. (Brainstorms bottle that integrates ketchup and
>   mustard.)
>
> “Television” host. (Erected the old Merv Griffin Show set in his
>   apartment and rebooted it.)
>
> Baker at H&H Bagels. (Briefly ends his strike.)
>
> Army soldier.  (“Classified.”)
>
> Hollywood sellout. (Sells option to The Coffee Table Book of Coffee
>   Tables to a "big Hollywood so-and-so" and retires to Florida.)
>
> Pretend patient. (Imitated wide range of diseased patients at a New
>   York teaching hospital.)
>
> Rickshaw entrepreneur. (Managed staff of homeless drivers.)

Comment: Great post and great link. I doubt he earned a cent from these schemes, though.

Comment: And let's not forget movie bootlegger. Kramer bought movie tickets and shot videos of first-run films. After a while his "work" was so popular he became a prima donna, demanding multiple cameras throughout the theater. As I recall, Jerry became his agent and worked to negotiate for the "star".

Comment: MY that's a comprehensive list! Good job :)

Comment: @BrettFromLA Actually it was Jerry that was the prima donna demanding multiple cameras for the next bootleg movie he was planning on shooting. Kramer ended up bootlegging the movie after Jerry refused to shoot it and being threatened by Brody (the movie dealer).

Comment: @richieaj Oh you're right! I got them switched in my mind.

Comment: Did Kramer actually WRITE "Astonishing Tales of the Sea", or did he just own a copy of it?

Answer (score -2):

Kramer did earn money for some of those in the list, including:

Murphy Brown
CK model
coffee table book
probably for make-your-own pizza (he did it in a restaurant)